# Select rows from a dataframe with a specific number of characters

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataframe like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(ticker = c("1TM", "ABL", "ABLIDD", "ABO", "ABSP", "ABT", "ACL", "ACLSTB", "ANGSBH", "ANM"))
```

I want to select the rows where the number of characters in the ticker column is equal to 3. How can I do this using either `subset` or `dplyr::filter()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic R code you can use `nchar` function like this:

```
df[nchar(as.character(df$ticker))==3,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
dplyr::filter(df, nchar(as.character(ticker))==3)
```

The as character is only necessary if the column is currently a factor.